# Regular Expression to Anonymize Names

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and the Find and Replace pattern with regular expressions to alter usernames such that only the first and last character of the screen name is shown, separated by exactly four asterisks (*). For example, "albobz" would become "a****z".

Usernames are listed directly after the cue "screen_name: " and I know I can find all the usernames using the regular expression:

`screen_name:\s([^\s]+)`

However, this expression won't store the first or last letter and I am not sure how to do it.

Here is a sample line:

```
February 3, 2018    screen_name: FR33Q  location: Europe    verified: false lang: en
```

Comment: It is always a good thing to produce a small set of demo data for regex questions.

Comment: How do I setup a demo, this is my first time asking a regex question

Comment: Just copy a few lines of your "data" into your question. Or use some regex-website like http://www.regexr.com  that allows saving and using providing the link inside your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1

You have to work with `\G` meta-character. In N++ using `\G` is kinda tricky.

Regex to find:

```
(?>(screen_name:\s+\S)|\G(?!^))\S(?=\S)
```

Breakdown:

- `(?>` Construct a non-capturing group (atomic)

  - `(` Beginning of first capturing group

    - `screen_name:\s\S` Match up to first letter of name
  - `)` End of first CG
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Continue from previous match
- `)` End of NCG
- `\S` Match a non-whitespace character
- `(?=\S)` Up to last but one character

Replace with:

```
\1*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4lh2K/2)

#### Method 2

Above solution substitutes each inner character with a `*` so length remains intact. If you want to put four number of `*`s without considering length you would search for:

```
(screen_name:\s+\S)(\S*)(\S)
```

and replace with: `\1****\3`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4lh2K/3)

Comment: This is really helpful. The only issue is that it captures the entire remainder of the line rather than just "screen_name: username". This text is proceeded by a tab, but when I put \t after the expression it still selects the whole row. Any ideas on fixing this?

Comment: What remainder you are talking about? Please add a real input string to your question.

Comment: There is no problem with your sample input too. Check it out here https://regex101.com/r/hx70wf/1 @Albobz